# Router Links not working after appending html angular2

Tags: angular

this is my code. And with some service function, on page scroll i am appending html to 'ul'. After appending html, router link is not working as i am changing the html of 'ul'. I want router link to work even after appending/changing html using pure js code or angular syntax. Strictly angular2/4.

```
<ul class="search-results" id="search-results" infinite-scroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
  <li *ngFor="let customer of icustomers">   
    <div>
    <h3><a [routerLink]="['/view-customer', customer._id]">{{customer.city}}</a></h3>
    <p>{{customer.pop}}</p>
    <p>{{customer.state}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Manually messing with the DOM while using Angular can lead to unpredictable behavior. You can surely do the same thing without manipulating the dom but using the renderer and the Angular API.

Comment: ok let me know which Angular API should i use to append data.